# Unable to add a margin on top of my component

Tags: html, css

I need to build two boxes which will have to be clickable, like these ones :
[image]

I currently have this, but I'm asking myself many simple questions that I can resolve: 
[image: *]

1) I have a fixed height for my `choice-box` component, is it possible to have it relatively to the page ?
2) How can I do to vertically center my `Upload New File` and `Download Template` texts ? I've tried to vertical align them but it does not work...
3) I would like to add a margin on top of my `Wrong move...` text, I tried a `margin-top` and a `padding-top`, but it also does not work... I think this is because my above component (`choice-boxes`) is not set properly
I'm kinda new in `css`, so if someone could help me that would be good !
Here are my `html` and `css` codes :

```
<div className="choice-box">
  <div className="head-title head-title-choice">
    What are you trying to do ?
  </div>

  <div className="choice-boxes">
    <div className="choice left-choice">
      Upload New File
    </div>

    <div className="choice right-choice">
      Download Template
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="under-choice">
    Wrong move, get back to Dashboard
  </div>
</div>
```

And :

```
.choice-box{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    height: 600px;

    border-radius: 5px;
}

.head-title-choice{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 2%;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.choice-boxes{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.choice{
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-top: 5%;
    height: 100%;
}

.left-choice{
    width: 44.5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

.right-choice{
    width: 44.5%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

.under-choice{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I can think of no reason to use `float` here. [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) will make all of your issues much easier to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of no reason to use `float` here. Try [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) for the layout, and [vh](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#viewport-relative-lengths) to make the height proportional to the window.

```css
.choice-box {
  text-align: center;
}

.choice-boxes {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.choice-boxes>* {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: blue;
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="choice-box">
  <div class="head-title head-title-choice">
    What are you trying to do ?
  </div>
  <div class="choice-boxes">
    <div class="choice left-choice">
      Upload New File
    </div>

    <div class="choice right-choice">
      Download Template
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="under-choice">
    Wrong move, get back to Dashboard
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks !! I had never hear about vh before